# How can a use a custom cursor on my BigCartel shop?

Tags: css, bigcartel

I'm trying to put a different cursor on my Big Cartel site but have never done anything with CSS. This is the best I could do by googling it and it's not working- any help is appreciated!

.module {
  cursor: url('https://downloads.totallyfreecursors.com/cursor_files/milhouse.cur'),url('https://downloads.totallyfreecursors.com/thumbnails/milhouse.gif') auto;
}

When I put this in nothing changes, the default cursors stay.